# GROUP_CONCAT on image blob?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I remember group_concat in mysql has character limit, that can be lifted before query. But even without this character limit, can I use it to have a list of images?

There are two tables,

Table #1, contains list of customers
Table #2, contains attachments (img/blob)

There are more rows per customer in second table. I would like to have 1 query that selects customers and attachment. I was going to use group_concat and than `explode(',')` in php

```
 SELECT wp_appointments.id,
        wp_appointments.full_name,
        wp_appointments.primary_email,
        wp_appointments.contact_tel,
        wp_appointments.appointment_date,
        wp_appointments.appointment_status,
        wp_appointments.payment_status,
        GROUP_CONCAT(wp_appointments_attch.id),
        wp_appointments_attch.attachement,
        wp_appointments_attch.attach_type
      FROM wp_appointments
RIGHT JOIN wp_appointments_attch
        ON wp_appointments_attch.appointment_id = wp_appointments.id
     WHERE service_type = 'c'
  GROUP BY wp_appointments.id
```

Comment: if your just going to `explode(',')` in php i don't see why you don't get septate rows in the first place

Comment: Also, just to note - RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare!

Comment: @Strawberry is correct, and in this example you probably want `LEFT JOIN` anyway. That is, I assume there can be no attachment without an appointment, but you might have an appointment with no attachment.

Comment: Livingstone, I presume

Comment: @BillKarwin service_type = c customers always have attachement.

Comment: @Dagon what is septate row?

Comment: the um, normal way you retrieve multiple rows from a db, with out concatenation from the  db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` on blobs, but you may not be able to use `explode()` on the resulting concatenated images to get the individual images out.

It's likely that the byte value 0x2C (same as ASCII for `,`) occurs by coincidence within a given image blob data. So if you rely on 0x2C as the separator between images, your `explode()` will accidentally split the image that contains that byte.

No matter what other separator you choose for your `GROUP_CONCAT()`, that separator might occur in the sequence of bytes of image data.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Any solutions?

Comment: Fetch images one per row. It might be easier to do this in a second query.